# Fix undeletable directory on removable NTFS drive

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs

Copied some large files on my NTFS-formatted portable hard drive, and I've accidentally pulled the plug before the cache was flushed. Upon remounting, the system didn't displayed any error messages, but the couldn't delete the last directory I copied. Everything else seems to be fine.

How can I remove that directory, preferable without formatting the drive?

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `dmesg` for more detailed error messages, but most likely the volume is corrupt and you will need to have Windows run chkdsk/scandisk on it to repair it.